# Move XML elements based on attribute value using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am in need to move XML element to the repective place based on the attribute value. The element `<m:footnote>` should be moved from `<m:endnote>` to the respective place when the attribute value of id is matching.

**Sample XML:**

```
<m:chapter xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
  <m:front>
    <m:p>This is <m:footnote id="1"/>para</m:p>
  </m:front>
  <m:body>
    <m:p>This is <m:footnote id="2"/>para</m:p>
    <m:p>This is <m:footnote id="3"/>para</m:p>
    <m:p>This is <m:footnote id="4"/>para</m:p>
  </m:body>
  <m:endnote>
    <m:footnote id="1">This is footnote 1</m:footnote>
    <m:footnote id="2">This is footnote 2</m:footnote>
    <m:footnote id="3">This is footnote 3</m:footnote>
    <m:footnote id="4">This is footnote 4</m:footnote>
  </m:endnote>
</m:chapter>
```

**Output required:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<m:chapter xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
<m:front>
<m:p>This is <m:footnote id="1">This is footnote 1</m:footnote>para</m:p>
</m:front>
<m:body>
<m:p>This is <m:footnote id="2">This is footnote 2</m:footnote>para</m:p>
<m:p>This is <m:footnote id="3">This is footnote 3</m:footnote>para</m:p>
<m:p>This is <m:footnote id="4">This is footnote 4</m:footnote>>para</m:p>
</m:body>
</m:chapter>
```

**XSLT tried:**

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" exclude-result-prefixes="m">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="m:chapter">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
<xsl:for-each select="child::*/descendant::m:footnote">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="not(parent::m:endnote)">
<xsl:if test="string(self::m:footnote/@id) = string('ancestor::m:chapter/m:endnote/m:footnote/@id')">
<xsl:copy-of select="m:chapter/m:endnote/m:footnote"/>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="m:endnote"></xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
      xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" exclude-result-prefixes="m">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:key name="kEndnote" match="m:endnote/m:footnote" use="@id"/>
  <xsl:key name="kFootnoteRef" match="m:p/m:footnote" use="@id"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="m:footnote">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
      <xsl:value-of select="key('kEndnote', @id)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="m:endnote[not(m:footnote[not(key('kFootnoteRef', @id))])]" />
  <xsl:template match="m:endnote/m:footnote[key('kFootnoteRef', @id)]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, this produces:

```
<m:chapter xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
  <m:front>
    <m:p>This is <m:footnote id="1">This is footnote 1</m:footnote>para</m:p>
  </m:front>
  <m:body>
    <m:p>This is <m:footnote id="2">This is footnote 2</m:footnote>para</m:p>
    <m:p>This is <m:footnote id="3">This is footnote 3</m:footnote>para</m:p>
    <m:p>This is <m:footnote id="4">This is footnote 4</m:footnote>para</m:p>
  </m:body>

</m:chapter>
```

When run on your sample input with the 2nd and 3rd `<m:p>` removed, this produces:

```
<m:chapter xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
  <m:front>
    <m:p>This is <m:footnote id="1">This is footnote 1</m:footnote>para</m:p>
  </m:front>
  <m:body>
    <m:p>This is <m:footnote id="4">This is footnote 4</m:footnote>para</m:p>
  </m:body>
  <m:endnote>

    <m:footnote id="2">This is footnote 2</m:footnote>
    <m:footnote id="3">This is footnote 3</m:footnote>

  </m:endnote>
</m:chapter>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, another thing is, if attribute value of id is not matching then '<m:endnote>' element with the <m:footnote> whose id is not matching should be retained.